# Harmonic Function for Upper Half Plane

Tags: complex-analysis

Can we construct a harmonic function $u$ on the upper half plane such that
$\lim\limits_{y->0+}u=1$ if $x>0$ and $\lim\limits_{y->0+}u=-1$ if $x<0$, where $z=x+yi$ ?

So far, I want to use Cayley Transform to redauce the unit disk case but
it is a little complicated.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Don't use the unit disk, use a parallel strip here.

Comment: Is there a Poisson kernel for the strip vertion? because we need to use it to construct doesnʼt it?

Comment: @DanielFischer
Can you give me more comment? Thank you very much!

Comment: For this, we need no Poisson kernel (but there are such kernels for half-planes and parallel strips). We can explicitly give such a function. Remember, if $f$ is holomorphic, then $\operatorname{Re} f$ and $\operatorname{Im} f$ are harmonic.

Comment: Thank you! But it is hard for me to construct a concrete function satisfying the boundary condition.

Comment: Look at the logarithm. That might give you an idea.

Comment: I try to construct it and $exp(Re((logz)^2))$ is my answer so far. Is it true? thank you again.

Comment: No, that's not harmonic. The solution is _much_ simpler. You know that $\operatorname{Im} (\log z) = \arg z$ [for compatibly chosen branches], so $\arg$ is harmonic on the upper half-plane. Look at what $\arg$ does.

Comment: Sorry. But it seems the function doesnʼt satisfy the boundary condition. Maybe, I misunderstood it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\arg$ denote the principal branch of the argument defined on the upper half-plane. Since $\arg z = \operatorname{Im} (\log z)$ [for the principal branch of the logarithm], $\arg$ is harmonic.

$\arg$ has a continuous extension to $\mathbb{H}\cup (\mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\})$, taking the value $0$ on the positive real half-axis, and the value $\pi$ on the negative real half-axis. These boundary conditions are of the desired type, just the values are different. An affine transformation achieves the desired boundary values:

$$u(z) = 1 - \frac{2}{\pi}\arg z$$

solves the problem.

Note that the solution is not unique, $u(z) + c\cdot \operatorname{Im} z$ has the same boundary values and is harmonic for all $c\in \mathbb{R}$. But $u$ is the unique *bounded* solution of the boundary value problem.

Comment: Sorry I am wondering why $exp(Re((logz)^2))$ is not harmonic? I think it is real part of $exp((logz)^2)$.

Comment: $\exp (\operatorname{Re} w)$ is the modulus of $\exp w$, not the real part. Writing $w = u+iv$, we have $e^w = e^u(\cos v + i\sin v)$, and hence $\operatorname{Re} (e^w) = e^u\cos v$. If $f$ is a real-valued harmonic function, then $\exp (f(z))$ is only harmonic if $f$ is (locally) constant, since we have $(e^f)_x = e^f\cdot f_x$, and then $(e^f)_{xx} = e^f\cdot (f_x^2 + f_{xx})$, whence $\Delta (e^f) = e^f\cdot \lVert \nabla f\rVert^2$, and that is only $0$ if $f$ is constant.

Comment: Thank you for the patience and I made the stupid mistake.